# Merge rows with the same date and id and append to the right side

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to merge rows with the same date and empIdn
from this dataframe:

```
,empIdn,date,time_0,time_1,time_2,time_3,time_4
0,191206,2020-12-02,07:22:50,12:15:21,12:15:23,12:35:35
1,191206,2020-12-02,17:27:46,17:27:49,,
```

and I want to achieve like this:

```
,empIdn,date,time_0,time_1,time_2,time_3,time_4,time_5,time_6
0,191206,2020-12-02,07:22:50,12:15:21,12:15:23,12:35:35,17:27:46,17:27:49
```

I would like to seek some help on how to do this, what I have done so far:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv("1.csv",index_col=[0])
df2 = pd.read_csv("2.csv",index_col=[0])

final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2], sort = True)
final_df.groupby(['date', 'empIdn']).agg(lambda x: x.tolist())

final_df.to_csv("fff.csv")
```

I'm new to Pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first `melt` your dataframe, order it by the current `index`, `empIdn` and `date`.

Then use a `groupby.cumcount()` method to create a new `time_` counter based of the above ordering.

The final step is to create a new `index` and then `unstack`.

Let's add a few records to your example to see what happens with non dupes.

The main difference between our expected outputs is that I drop `time_4` for the first row due to it being `NA` if this is not intended behavior then you can first `fillna` on the first value of a duplicate row with an arbitrary value.

Something like `df = df.fillna(df[df.duplicated(subset=['empIdn','date'],keep='last')].fillna(-1))`

```
print(df)

   empIdn       date    time_0    time_1    time_2    time_3  time_4
0  191206 2020-12-02  07:22:50  12:15:21  12:15:23  12:35:35     NaN
1  191206 2020-12-02  17:27:46  17:27:49       NaN       NaN     NaN
2  191207 2020-12-02  07:22:50  12:15:21  12:15:23  12:35:35     NaN
3  191207 2020-11-02  07:22:50  12:15:21  12:15:23  12:35:35     NaN
4  191207 2020-12-02  17:27:46  17:27:49       NaN       NaN     NaN
```

Based on the above example, we can expect an ouput of three rows, where `empIdn` 191206 and 191207 are duplicated by date and `192017` left alone since its not a duplicate.

---

```
df1 = (
    pd.melt(df.reset_index(), id_vars=["empIdn", "date", "index"], var_name="time")
    .dropna(subset=["value"]) ## we don't care about nulls here.
    .sort_values(["empIdn", "date", "index"])
)

df1['time'] = 'time_' + df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(['empIdn','date']).cumcount()).astype(str)['key']

final = df1.set_index(["empIdn", "date", "time"]).drop("index", 1).unstack("time").droplevel(
    0, 1
).reset_index()

print(final)
```

[image]

---

with `-1` as a filler value.

[image]

## Unpacking `cumcount`

from the below you can see it's clear when the `key` increments to create our new `key` column -

The key here is to `order` by your original index and `groupby` `empIdn` and `date`

```
print(df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(['empIdn','date']).cumcount()))
    empIdn        date index    time     value key
0   191206  2020-12-02     0  time_0  07:22:50   0
5   191206  2020-12-02     0  time_1  12:15:21   1
10  191206  2020-12-02     0  time_2  12:15:23   2
15  191206  2020-12-02     0  time_3  12:35:35   3
1   191206  2020-12-02     1  time_0  17:27:46   4 # < -- new row in original dataframe.
6   191206  2020-12-02     1  time_1  17:27:49   5 # < -- we want to increment these to time_4 / time_5
3   191207  2020-11-02     3  time_0  07:22:50   0
8   191207  2020-11-02     3  time_1  12:15:21   1
13  191207  2020-11-02     3  time_2  12:15:23   2
18  191207  2020-11-02     3  time_3  12:35:35   3
2   191207  2020-12-02     2  time_0  07:22:50   0
7   191207  2020-12-02     2  time_1  12:15:21   1
12  191207  2020-12-02     2  time_2  12:15:23   2
17  191207  2020-12-02     2  time_3  12:35:35   3
4   191207  2020-12-02     4  time_0  17:27:46   4
9   191207  2020-12-02     4  time_1  17:27:49   5
```

Comment: @CarlojuneCaimen operational data is hard to manage but once you get the hang of it you'll be flying. Good luck with your analysis, hope the steps were clear. Feel free to ask a new question if you need any more help.

Comment: I'm just very curious about this lines
    df1['time'] = 'time_' + 
    df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(['empIdn','date']).cumcount()).astype(str)['key']

final = df1.set_index(["empIdn", "date", "time"]).drop("index", 1).unstack("time").droplevel(
    0, 1
).reset_index()

Comment: @CarlojuneCaimen run `df1.assign(key=df1.groupby(['empIdn','date']).cumcount()).astype(str)` on its own and you'll understand. the latter is just setting an index before pivoting your columns, its one of many ways to pivot in pandas, i prefer it but others prefer using `pd.crosstab` or `pd.pivot`